# /api/Account/ExternalLogin return HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, google-authentication

I'm following the tutorial on this page (http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.sg/2016/12/aspnet-web-api-google-authentication.html) and once I reached step 3, when I call to http://localhost:61358/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true it returns error 404.

Could anybody please advise what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Specify your IP address instead of localhost? Local host cannot be resolved on distant machines

Comment: Do you have `Account` controller that is part of API? Does this `http://localhost:61358/Account/ExternalLogins` work?

Answer (score 0):

He adds the account controller in a later step. Patience, young padawan.